# ImageMagick - PECL issue - Cannot locate header file MagickWand.h

Tags: imagemagick, pecl, whm

We are getting this error while installing ImageMagick PECL:

> checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... found in
>   /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config checking if ImageMagick version is at
>   least 6.2.4... found version 6.8.6 Q16  checking for MagickWand.h
>   header file...  configure: error: Cannot locate header file
>   MagickWand.h  ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/imagick/configure --with-imagick'
>   failed  extension imagick.so installed in /usr/local/lib/php.ini 
>   /usr/local/bin/php does not have a php.ini Tidying
>   /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/etc/php.ini... No changes

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 22):

This thread is old, but I solved this issue today on a Centos 7 by installing ImageMagick-devel package:

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this appears to also work fine on C8 using `dnf -y install IMageMagick-devel`.  thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 19):

Steps:

1. apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
2. /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install imagick
3. gedit /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
4. add "extension=imagick.so" to php.ini

Answer (score 4):

Probably its looking for the file MagickWand.h and unable to see that file in the defined location. Try these steps

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
tar zxf imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
```

Edit the file `imagick-3.1.0RC2/config.m4` line number **55**.

Make changes like this, from

```
if test -r $WAND_DIR/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h;
```

to

```
if test -r $WAND_DIR/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h;
```

Note this difference made in the imagick version number. After that try the conventional installation procedures

```
cd imagick-3.1.0RC2
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: You can easily install the imagick using yum. try "yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel"

Comment: Hi Leo, I get this error after ./configure : "checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program." Any idea ?

Comment: Are you having this error after the mentioned error "configure: error: Cannot locate header file MagickWand.h". If so did you tried the steps I have given above.

Comment: Yes, I edited the file config.m4 on line 55 : "if test -r $WAND_DIR/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h; then".
I am on Mac Lion with Mamp.

Comment: Here is pretty good way for [Mamp](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php) Go through the steps and try to finish installation. All the best :)

Comment: Thanks ! I've followed the guide on Mac OS X and it works, I can see the wizard image ("display logo.gif"). However I can't make it work in MAMP, I have this error in my php error log : "[02-Aug-2013 07:51:11] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0" . Any idea ?

Comment: That means imagick.so module is not loading by your php. what is your php version? Put a [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) in the root directory of your website and check the "Loaded Configuration" and make sure that there is an entry like "extension=imagick.so" in it. Also look for "Extension Directory"(from phpinfo) and check whether imagick.so is placed there. Did you had any sort of issues at the time of installation?

Comment: There is "extension=imagick.so" in my php.ini but there is no file "imagick.so" in my extension directory (_extension_dir_ in php info). Do I have to download it and paste it here ? I've tried a "locate imagick.so" in my Terminal but nothing found. I did not have any issues during my last installation. Thanks for your help !

Comment: So its obvious that php understands that imagick has been installed in the server by the line extension=imagick.so but unable to locate the extension file in the extension_dir so its causing php error. Try downloading the [imagick.so](http://www.koderz.org/uploads/media/imagick.so) using wget command to the server's extension_dir and provide the exec permission using "chmod +x imagick.so". let me know if that helped you. If not you needed to download the imagick.so file for the exact version you have installed in the server to the extension_dir with exec permission. :)

Comment: Hi Pascal issue fixed?

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for the followup and sorry for the late answer. It didn't work and I had to keep going so I used GD instead, but Imagick would make my code easier. I did what you said and put the imagick.so in the extension_dir folder and here is the error in the php_error.log on startup :

Comment: **[09-Aug-2013 08:21:51] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 in Unknown on line 0** . Thanks again

Comment: Is Imagick shows in phpinfo(). Or try php -m | grep magick from command line.

Comment: >no suitable image found, >Did find: //imagick.so unknown file type These errors means that php detects the imagickmodule but the architectureyou have used is different. Try toggling your Mac Lion test machines architecture. [This](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3773) link will help you to do that. Otherwise you needed to replace the imagick.so in the extension dir to of correct architecture. You will get imagick.so module in both arch. You needed to google that to get. :)

Comment: I tried toggling to 32 bits but My mac freezes.
I have to find imagick.so for Mac 64 bits. I'll update this post if I find it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this http://thomas.bindzus.me/2013/08/11/building-pecl-imagick-for-php-5-5-1-on-centos-6-4/ can be of some help to others.

The solution described by Leo Prince almost worked for me, just had to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and perhaps that's just my server setup which isn't as perfect as it should be.

Here is what I did step-by-step (I'm running CentOS 6.4, Apache 2.4.6, and PHP 5.5.1):

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
tar zxf imagick-3.1.0RC2.tgz
cd imagick-3.1.0RC
phpize
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
./configure –with-imagick
make
make install
echo extension=imagick.so > /etc/php.d/imagick.ini
service httpd restart
php -m | grep imagick
```

Comment: Yeah sometimes exporting environmental variable is needed if it is not included in the default system paths. :)

Comment: I had to change certain things for my cpanel installation but it mostly worked. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas Binduz  I get "checking build system type... Invalid configuration `–with-imagick': machine –with' not recognized` and 
`configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub –with-imagick failed"`. My "/usr/local/lib/" is empty.

Answer (score -1):

First run following commands

```
1. "WHM Home » Software » Rebuild RPM Database"

2. yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel

3. yum install pcre-devel
```

Then go to

```
Go to WHM -> Software -> Module Installers -> PHP Pecl (manage). On the 
box below “Install a PHP Pecl” enter “imagick” and click “Install Now” 
button – that’s all.  Restart Apache.
```

Above steps worked for me.