# Unable to install php imagick

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, imagick, pecl

I'm trying to install Imagick as its required for an extension I want to use for my project.

I've tried to install it on my ArchLinux like:

```
pacman -S imagemagick
pecl install imagick
```

The pecl install ends up throwing me the following error:

```
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... checking Testing /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /usr/bin/MagickWand-config... It exists
found in /usr/bin/MagickWand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... found version 7.0.7 Q16 HDRI
checking for MagickWand.h or magick-wand.h header... configure: error: Unable to find MagickWand.h or magick-wand.h header
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-imagick' failed
```

Any help as to how to get Imagick installed on my ArchLinux would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageMagick - PECL issue - Cannot locate header file MagickWand.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836893/imagemagick-pecl-issue-cannot-locate-header-file-magickwand-h)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PHP#imagemagick

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836893/imagemagick-pecl-issue-cannot-locate-header-file-magickwand-h was for Imagick 3.1, but Imagick 3.4.3 is different.

Comment: ImageMagick 7 may not be compatible with the version of Imagick you are trying to install, since ImageMagick 7 had different commands, e.g. magick replaces the ImageMagick 6 convert command.